# pyplot.show() fails to produce graph, causes IDLE to restart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've just installed Python 2.7.1 on my MacBook (running Snow Leopard), and I've also installed the [scipy superpack](http://stronginference.com/scipy-superpack/).  NumPy and matplotlib import just fine, but when I invoke pyplot.show(), either in the interpreter or in a script, a blank window appears for just a second and then IDLE restarts.  No graph appears.

I wrote an extremely simple test script which appears in the screenshot below.  It creates two lists, prints them, plots the two lists against each other, and outputs the plot to a png.  This it does successfully, and you can see that the png indeed exists in the appropriate folder.  So pyplot.savefig() works as expected.  But then I invoked pyplot.show(), and you can see that the interpreter has restarted.

How can I fix this?

[image: screen shot of python output]

### Update

As per @Blender's suggestion, I added plt.show() to the script and ran it from Terminal.  This time it produced the following error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.1.0-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 235, in resize
    self.show()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.1.0-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 239, in draw
    tkagg.blit(self._tkphoto, self.renderer._renderer, colormode=2)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.1.0-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 19, in blit
    tk.call("PyAggImagePhoto", photoimage, id(aggimage), colormode, id(bbox_array))
TclError
```

Comment: Try running it from a Terminal window. Just type in `python` and do the same as you did for IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably due to a **conflict between idle and the matplotlib backend**.  Instead of using idle, try using ipython, which is included in the superpack, and start ipython in the pylab mode, i.e., run `ipython -pylab` at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 
         import pylab
         pylab.show()
this will display the graph in separate window.